# How do I access an instance of a class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, instance

I have a user class defined in `UserClass.swift` like this:

```
class User {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var phone:String
    var email:String

    init(id:Int, name:String, phone:String, email:String){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

In my `ProfileViewController` I call a method on `viewDidLoad` called `getUserData`.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getUserData { myUser in
            self.userNameLabel.text = myUser.name
        }
}
```

`getUserData` pings my API and then instantiates and instance of the `User` class.

```
func getUserData(completionHandler:(User)->()) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "apiEndPoint")
        .responseJSON { response in

        if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {

            let userData = JSON(value)
            let userName = userData["name"].string!
            let userId = userData["id"].int!
            let userPhone = userData["phone"].string!
            let userEmail = userData["email"].string!

            let myUser = User(id:userId, name:userName, phone:userPhone, email:userEmail)

            print("user: \(myUser.name)")

            completionHandler(myUser)

        }
    }
}
```

I then pass that instance with a callback to the `ProfileViewController` so that I can update a label. This works great.

The problem is that now I want to look at a different property of the `User` instance `myUser` in a different place, outside of the callback. Eventually I want to get the user's id, but for now I'm just trying to access the instance at all, so I'm looking again at updating a label with the user's name:

```
class MyActivitiesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myActTempLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            self.myActTempLabel.text = myUser.name
    }
}
```

This is giving me an error of `Use of unresolved identifier 'myUser'`. How do I access the instance of User that I already created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep a reference to the User object in a singleton in order to access it every where. Basically in cases like this you have a singleton class called say `CurrentUser`

```
class CurrentUser {
  static var sharedInstance = CurrentUser()
  var user:User?
}
```

Then in your network call or perhaps in the completion handler of the first view controller you where you know the first time the user is obtained you can set the User instance to the CurrentUser singleton.

`CurrentUser.sharedInstance.user = myUser`

Later you can use `CurrentUser.sharedInstance.user` in all the places where you want to get the user details.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple . just create a ref of User in your class and assign myUser to it 
like:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
var user: User?
@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getUserData { myUser in
      self.user = myUser
      self.userNameLabel.text = myUser.name
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

your instance myUser is just existed in your block. You need to create a variable to store this

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
var user:User?
@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getUserData { myUser in
        self.userNameLabel.text = myUser.name
        user = myUser
    }
```

}

now you can use "user" property to access outside your block